# How to stop Requiredfieldvalidator working on cancel click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core-mvc

I am having an issue with the Requiredfieldvalidator. look at the below image

[image]

From the above Pic, When I Click on the **Add New** button the Red color hilighted div will appear, If I click on **Save** button, the Building desctiption button is showing an rfv error. It is fine upto here, but. My issue is when I click on the **Cancel** button and again click on the **Add New** button. I am still getting that Building description as show in the Image.

```
<a class="col-md-1 html5buttons" onclick="ToggleProjectAddBuilding(true)" id="Addbuildingsave">Add New</a>

<div class="col-md-8">
                                    <select asp-for="BuildingDescriptionId" class="chosen-select form-control required" asp-items="@(ViewBag.BuildingTypes)">
                                        <option value="">--Select Building Type--</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <span asp-validation-for="BuildingDescriptionId" id="Customererror" class="text-danger"></span>
                                </div>


 <div class="col-md-offset-8 col-md-9">
                                    <button id="btnSavebuilding" type="submit" class="btn btn-w-m btn-primary">Save</button>
                                    <a class="btn btn-w-m btn-warning" onclick="ToggleProjectAddBuilding(false)">Cancel</a>
                                </div>
```

below is the Function code which i have tried to do:

```
function ToggleProjectAddBuilding(toggle) {    
    if (toggle) {
        $('#formBuilding').slideDown();
    }
    else {
        $('#formBuilding').slideUp();
        $('#buildingids').val('');
        $('#BuildingDescriptionId-error').html('');
        //$('.chosen-select').attr('data-rule-required', 'false');
        //$('BuildingDescriptionId').find('select option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true);
        //$('#BuildingDescriptionId').attr('selected', 'selected');
        //$("#BuildingDescriptionId").val($("#BuildingDescriptionId option:first").val());
        //$("#BuildingDescriptionId").prop("selectedIndex", 0);
        $("#BuildingDescriptionId option:selected").prop("selected", false);


        //$('#ProjectBuildingFloors_Id').val(data.ProjectBuildingFloors.Id);
        $('#BuildingType').val('');
        $('input#basementtrue').iCheck("uncheck");
        $('input#basementfalse').iCheck("check");
        $('input#isbasementfinishedtrue').iCheck("uncheck");
}
```

Comment: Right click on `dropdown`, Inspect Element, and post what has been rendered as html for the `select option`, when error is present..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao: here's the Select options code,  <select class="chosen-select form-control required input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Building Type field is required." id="BuildingDescriptionId" name="BuildingDescriptionId" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="BuildingDescriptionId-error" aria-invalid="true">
                                        <option value="">--Select Building Type--</option>
                                    <option value="1">Test building Type</option>
</select>

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Pugazh: I tried to use this in the Jsfiddle.net, but I will not exactly how it is in the Image, I used most of the Bootstrap and some dynamic functions.

Comment: Ok, in your else part, you add this - `$('select.chosen-select').removeClass('input-validation-error')`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao: Yes please, It will help some one also  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, in your else part, you add this - `$('select.chosen-select').removeClass('input-validation-error')`

That will do the trick..